# getview not called after notifydatasetchanged

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

So i was working on a realtime listview , i need list view to update on button click so did these :

```
private void ReloadData(){
    DataList.clear();
    try{
        for (int i =0;i<ItemsCount;i++){
            TempItem=new STRUCTS.STRUCT_ProductItem();
            TempItem.setName(dbh.ReadDefine(ProductID,i+"","name")+"");//Read name if there is any set
            TempItem.setImgs(Uri.parse(dbh.ReadDefine(ProductID,i+"","img")+""));//Read image if there is any set
            TempItem.setInfo("PR"+i);//Desc

            Log.i("TAG", "ReloadData: "+IsOn[i]);//Is product avalible

            TempItem.setToggled(IsOn[i]);
            DataList.add(TempItem);

        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERRORCATCHER", "OnForLoop (Fill Product Data): "+ex.getMessage() );
    }
    //


    if(!IsAdapterSet){

        adapter = new LISTCUSTOM_ProductITEM(MyActivity.this,DataList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        IsAdapterSet=true;
    }else{


        try {


            adapter.swapItems(DataList);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

**SwapItems on my custom adapter:**

```
 public void swapItems(ArrayList<STRUCTS.STRUCT_ProductItem> list) throws InterruptedException {
    DataList=list;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

This is not giving any errors and as i can see from Log the New Items are succesfully added and their data is new

listview wont update itself ! so when I click the button which runs ReloadData()
it have no effect on listview ...

Acually This log isent running  :

```
      @Override
    public View getView(final int CPosition, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            final STRUCTS.STRUCT_ProductItem Currect_Item=DataList.get(CPosition);
        Log.i("TAG", "View updated : "+Currect_Item.gettoggled());
/*Define stuff*/
 itempicture.setImageURI(Currect_Item.getImgs());
/*More listview update stuff*/
```

It wont log ViewUpdated when I click that button and it wont change any of listview elements

BUT when I scroll listview so items arent visible then I scroll back their data is updated !

> GetView is runned when a item lose visibility then gain it again

Why Notifydatachanged wont update UI / Run the GetView on my custom adapter ?

Comment: try first to clear items in `DataList` then use `DataList.addAll(list.getData())`;

Answer (score 1):

try this to code

```
     private void ReloadData(){
        DataList.clear();
        if(!IsAdapterSet){

    adapter = new LISTCUSTOM_ProductITEM(MyActivity.this,DataList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    IsAdapterSet=true;
}
        try{
            for (int i =0;i<ItemsCount;i++){
                TempItem=new STRUCTS.STRUCT_ProductItem();
                TempItem.setName(dbh.ReadDefine(ProductID,i+"","name")+"");//Read name if there is any set
                TempItem.setImgs(Uri.parse(dbh.ReadDefine(ProductID,i+"","img")+""));//Read image if there is any set
                TempItem.setInfo("PR"+i);//Desc

                Log.i("TAG", "ReloadData: "+IsOn[i]);//Is product avalible

                TempItem.setToggled(IsOn[i]);
                DataList.add(TempItem);

            }
        adapter.swapItems(DataList);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERRORCATCHER", "OnForLoop (Fill Product Data): "+ex.getMessage() );
        }


    }
    }
```

in Adapter class

```
public void swapItems(ArrayList<STRUCTS.STRUCT_ProductItem> list) throws InterruptedException {
DataList.addAll(list);
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

Comment: It makes list to scroll to first and GetView isent running when notifydatasetchanged is runned it actaully made it worse?

Comment: DataList.addAll without clearing it first? it made my list full of duplicate items and still not working

Comment: @Disco4uf change your code in adapter DataList.addAll(list); to your previous code

Comment: i thought you want to add previous data new data

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
private void ReloadData(){
    ArrayList<STRUCTS.STRUCT_ProductItem> list = new ArrayList<>;
    try {
        for (int i =0;i<ItemsCount;i++) {
            TempItem= new STRUCTS.STRUCT_ProductItem();
            TempItem.setName(dbh.ReadDefine(ProductID,i+"","name")+"");//Read name if there is any set
            TempItem.setImgs(Uri.parse(dbh.ReadDefine(ProductID,i+"","img")+""));//Read image if there is any set
            TempItem.setInfo("PR"+i);//Desc

            Log.i("TAG", "ReloadData: "+IsOn[i]);//Is product avalible

            TempItem.setToggled(IsOn[i]);
            list.add(TempItem);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERRORCATCHER", "OnForLoop (Fill Product Data): "+ex.getMessage() );
    }

    DataList.clear();
    DataList.addAll(list);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```